# Optimizing MySQL query with multiple joins and Sub query

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

I am using the following query to get data from 10 table, It is working fine but quite slow, Is there any way to Optimizing the query.

Query: SELECT emi.emi_due_date,users.usr_mobile,users.usr_id,concat_ws(" ",users.usr_fname,users.usr_mname,users.usr_lname) as borrower,users.usr_status,users.usr_curnt_city, users.usr_email,emi.loan_id,emi.emi_show_date,sum(emi.emi_amount)-sum(ifnull(emi.settled_amount,0)) as due_amount,cb.cb_type,blr.bloan_collection_executive_id,blr.pp_allow,blr.bloan_legal_team_id,blr.bloan_legal_team_status,concat_ws(" ",cp.cp_fname,cp.cp_lname) as cp_name,cp.cp_mobile,cp.cp_firm_name,cp.cp_type,bg.guarantor_name,bg.guarantor_contact,pl.ecs_date,pd.p2p_date,

(SELECT instrument FROM borrower_payment_master WHERE loan_id = emi.loan_id order by id desc limit 0,1) as last_pmode,

(SELECT IFNULL(DATE_FORMAT(emi_show_date - INTERVAL 1 MONTH,"%m-%Y"),"") FROM emi AS e WHERE e.loan_id=emi.loan_id and e.emi_status < 2 ORDER by e.emi_show_date ASC limit 1) as paid_till,

(select payment_date from borrower_payment_master as bp where bp.loan_id=emi.loan_id order by bp.id desc limit 1) as last_emi_paid FROM emi AS emi

INNER JOIN borrower_loan_reg_requests AS blr ON emi.loan_id=blr.bloan_id

INNER JOIN users AS users ON users.usr_id=blr.bloan_user_id

INNER JOIN borrower_loan_disbursed_funds AS blf ON blf.df_bloan_id=emi.loan_id

LEFT JOIN channel_partners AS cp ON cp.cp_id=users.usr_cp_referral_id

LEFT JOIN borrower_posted_loans AS pl ON pl.pl_bloan_id=emi.loan_id

LEFT JOIN collection_bucket AS cb ON cb.cb_loan_id=emi.loan_id AND cb.cb_status = 1

LEFT JOIN borrower_guarantors AS bg ON bg.guarantor_borrower_id=users.usr_id

LEFT JOIN p2p_dates AS pd ON pd.p2p_loan_id=emi.loan_id AND pd.p2p_status = 1

WHERE emi.emi_status<2  AND emi.emi_amount != 0

AND (SELECT count(*) FROM borrower_payment_master as pm WHERE pm.loan_id = emi.loan_id

AND MONTH(pm.payment_date) = "'.date('m').'" AND YEAR(pm.payment_date) = "'.date('Y').'") = 0

AND (select s.settlement_date as sdate from settlement as s WHERE emi.loan_id=s.loan_id limit 1) !=""

group by emi.loan_id order by emi.loan_id desc

Comment: please apply formatting to this query. Also provide `EXPLAIN {query}` output. `SHOW CREATE TABLE {tablenames}` from tables used would help too. Use date range comparisions for `pm.payment_date`.

Comment: Too many successive left joins will have issue. Give us your minimal table structures and what you are trying to achieve. Maybe there is otherway around. Or, table structures can be changed

Comment: Simplify the problem. No sane person is going to wade through all that